# convert html links to markdown using command sed

Tags: html, sed, hyperlink, markdown

I am editing a bash script to convert html into markdown and i found myself stuck with that tag :

```
<a href="www.link.com">Link</a>
```

which should looks like this in markdown

```
[Link](www.link.com)
```

Comment: See this solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/582424/80259

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found something with sed and the pattern selectors  \1 \2

```
echo '<a href="www.link.com">Link</a>' | sed 's/<a href="\(.*\)">\(.*\)<\/a>/[\2](\1)/'
[Link](www.link.com)
```

The pattern you place between parenthesis \( and \) will be stored in a variable \1 then the next one will be in \2 ...

Comment: I have done something slightly different: `sed -r 's/<a href="(.*)">(.*)<.*/[\2](\1)/g'`

Comment: Both solutions given so far will also take other parameters like `target="_blank"` or `rel="noopener"`  to the markdown syntax, which is unwanted.